# solve TWANG package svyglm.survey.design error using mnps function

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

i have been trying to peform the mnps function in R but I receive this error message each time:

Error in svyglm.survey.design(x ~ t, design) :
all variables must be in design= argument

this is my code:

```
mnps_1 <- mnps(M02M_CONGPAT ~ M2_M_PPD + M00M2_COUPLE  + 
M00M2_PEREACC + M00X_AUTPATHO + M0_M_age + M0_P_age + M0_M_nation + 
M0_P_nation + mother_diploma + father_diploma + mom_profession + 
dad_profession + fchild + mother_medicine + M2_P_PPD + 
distress_mod_parent + distress_sev_parent + number_household + 
child_living_sit + Fwanted_child + Mwanted_child + M2_conflict_ab + 
M2_conflict_dp + M2_conflict_bp + M2_conflict + M0_zone + 
M0_siblingbis + cdi_pere + relative_poverty + relationship_mother,
data = impute_1,
n.trees = 10000,
interaction.depth = 3,
shrinkage = 0.01,
perm.test.iters = 0,
stop.method = c("es.mean", "ks.max"),
estimand = "ATE",
verbose = FALSE)
if("pair" != "none"){                                 
baltab<-bal.table(mnps_1, collapse.to="pair")
 
 
 
 write.table(baltab,file='propensity_scores_impute_1.csv',row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE,sep=',',na='.')}
```

error:

```
Error in svyglm.survey.design(x ~ t, design) : 
all variables must be in design= argument
```

can someone help me? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your data variable, `impute_1`, is a tibble. `bal.table()` doesn't function properly when a tibble is supplied to `mnps()`. I was able to replicate this error by supplying a tibble to `mnps()`, and this is a common problem in older packages, but there may be a different cause.

If this is what's going on, try re-running `mnps()` replacing `impute_` with `as.data.frame(impute_1)`.